# fp-ts Return all left values from an Either[] sequence

Tags: fp-ts

I have a list of strings, `string[]`

I map a validate function that returns `Either<Error, string>[]`

I want `[Error[], string[]]`, all validation errors and all validated strings.

Can `sequence(Either.Applicative)` or `traverse(Either.Applicative)` return all errors encountered? I only received `Either<Error, string[]>`, just the first error returned. Would I need to write my own Applicative, something with a Semigroup that merges lefts and rights?

I was able get all Errors by changing `map` to `reduce` with a `fold`.

I also thought of reversing the validation eithers, and running it twice. One function returns the valid strings, one returns the errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`traverse` returns an `Either`, but you want to accumulate both `Left`s and `Right`s. You can `map` over the inputs and then separate the elements.

```js
import * as A from 'fp-ts/lib/Array';
import * as E from 'fp-ts/lib/Either';
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/lib/function';

declare const input: string[];
declare function validate(input: string): E.Either<Error, string>;

const result = pipe(input, A.map(validate), A.separate);
// result.left: Error[]
// result.right: string[]
```

Comment: How would this work with `TaskEither`s?

Comment: @AdamArold https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-sunset-4thm5z